# Need to manually activate bluetooth at every boot/wake-up

Tags: bluetooth, gnome-shell, systemd, 23.10

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10, bluetooth starts turned off on Gnome shell whenever I reboot or wake up from suspend. I need to go there and turn on the Bluetooth pill in the menu, while I believe this should start on by default (it worked like that in 23.04). Once its turned on, everything works just fine, but I have this extra step each time. Why is that? Tried to enable the bluetooth service under systemd, but it is already enabled, so how I might fix this slightly annoying thing?

Comment: Same issue here! But it started last week while I upgraded to 23.10 months ago.